# Unmarshalling JSON with invalid character

Tags: json, go

I have json coming in from a web service which can potentially be invalid for json unmarshalling due to it being human entered values. I also don't have control over these values because they come in through an external API. Is there a clean way to sanitize the input to remove all invalid values from a `[]byte` before unmarshalling to a struct?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

type Test struct {
    Field string `json:"test"`
}

func main() {
    test := `{"test": " "}` //this is a tab character
    obj := Test{}
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(test) , &obj); err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%v", err)
    }
}
```

And then the returned error for this is:

`invalid character '\t' in string literal`

Comment: `strings.Replace(test, "\t", "\\t", -1)` will work, unless the JSON data is pretty printed with tab characters.

Comment: You should contact the maintainers of the external API and tell them to produce valid JSON (or otherwise they should stop saying they send JSON responses).

Comment: You shouldn't waste your energy parsing arbitrary text. Looks they don't escape values in their JSON text, which means if their user enters a quotation mark, then their response will just blow up? Hell, users can just construct JSON data which if they input, they can basically inject any response they want (_"JSON injection"_ attack...).

Comment: What icza said. If you insist on consuming this API you are making yourself vulnerable. There is simply no reliable way to correct malformed JSON. You can't know if a literal tab character is supposed to be part of a string value, or if there's a missing quote somewhere which would make the tab insignificant. Only the producer knows that.